Sending request from postman and its stuck on sending request. i am trying to upload video to mongodb
i am using multer and gridFsBucket to store a video on mongo but when i send request it gets stuck on sending request from postman
this is code for my uploadMovie controller
const uploadMovie = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    let responseSent = false;
    const filePath = req.file.path;
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    req.file.stream = fileStream;

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    try {
        if (!req.file) {
            responseSent = true;
            return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
        }


        const db = client.db('videos');
        const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db);

        const filename = req.file.originalname;
        const contentType = req.file.mimetype;

        const uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStream(filename, { contentType });

        uploadStream.on('error', (error) => {
            if (!responseSent) {
                responseSent = true;
                console.error('Error uploading video:', error);
                res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
            }
        });

        uploadStream.on('finish', () => {
            if (!responseSent) {
                responseSent = true;
                console.log('Video uploaded successfully!');
                res.status(201).send('Video uploaded');
            }
        });

        req.file.stream.pipe(uploadStream);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting or uploading:', error);
        if (!responseSent) {
            res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
        }
    } finally {
        // Close the MongoDB client
        if (client) {
            await client.close();
        }
    }
});


this is code for my multer config
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

module.exports = storage;

video is getting uploaded to mongodb and also i can see it in my uploads folder but in postman i am not getting any final result like video is uploaded successfully
thank you for helping!
my multer config
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

module.exports = storage;

my upload video controller
const uploadMovie = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    let responseSent = false;
    const filePath = req.file.path;
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    req.file.stream = fileStream;

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    try {
        if (!req.file) {
            responseSent = true;
            return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
        }


        const db = client.db('videos');
        const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db);

        const filename = req.file.originalname;
        const contentType = req.file.mimetype;

        const uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStream(filename, { contentType });

        uploadStream.on('error', (error) => {
            if (!responseSent) {
                responseSent = true;
                console.error('Error uploading video:', error);
                res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
            }
        });

        uploadStream.on('finish', () => {
            if (!responseSent) {
                responseSent = true;
                console.log('Video uploaded successfully!');
                res.status(201).send('Video uploaded');
            }
        });

        req.file.stream.pipe(uploadStream);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting or uploading:', error);
        if (!responseSent) {
            res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
        }
    } finally {
        // Close the MongoDB client
        if (client) {
            await client.close();
        }
    }
});


i am getting video in uploads folder and mongodb but not getting result in postman

I'm reading your code but can't really see a problem.  Did the console.log('Video uploaded successfully!'); occur server-side?

no it did not console logged on server side

with express, in case of any error and it isn't handled correctly express doesn't send response back. add try catch and figure out what error either via console logging or responding as response
